# How can I convert a geocell to lat/long?

Tags: latitude-longitude

I use GeoModel on app engine--super awesome, I love it for doing location based searches. However, I'd like to actualy also graph a geocell on to a map. Does anyone know how I can convert a geocell back to long/lat, such that I have 4 long/lat coordinates that define the vertices of the geocell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function `compute_box` (line 408 in [geocell.py](http://code.google.com/p/geomodel/source/browse/trunk/geo/geocell.py)) takes the cell as an argument and returns the corresponding instance of `geotypes.Box` -- an object with attributes `east`, `west`, `south`, `north`, corresponding to the min and max lat/long of the cell.

See [geotypes.py](http://code.google.com/p/geomodel/source/browse/trunk/geo/geotypes.py) line 47 for all details about the `Box` class.